# CanCan Gem: Don't want to load the abilities upfront

Tags: authorization, cancan

My app has way too many privileges and actions, so loading all of them upfront for a given user session takes a lot of time (400 ms or more, even for negligible amount of data). Say, the user makes an "index" method request on a controller and the subject (model class) is Model. I would like for CanCan to only define that single ability even though the actual .YML file has all of the abilities configured.

Along with this, I don't these abilities to be all loaded for an "admin" user who can do pretty much everything.

How can I solve the above 2 problems above?